# Unique id generator based on text corpus

Tags: uniqueidentifier, identifier, unique-id

I want to build a shakespeare unique id generator that can generate up to 32 character long unique ids based on a shakespeare text corpus. I did some research but I couldn't find any algorithm that can generate unique ids based on a text corpus.

So the generator can create unique hashes like "Hellemptyalldevilshere".

Does anybody know an algorithm to generate this ids?